# Create rmarkdown table?

Tags: r-markdown

Is it possible to generate a markdown table that looks like this one?

[image: table]

I found [this documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#tables), but I cannot produce anything like what I want.

Comment: is using stright html in your markdown document an option?

Comment: Yes. Although, a package that makes things easier is always preferable. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No col/row spanning or colors are supported by markdown -- so if you want to create such table, you have to decide on the preferred output, where basically you have two choices: PDF or HTML. You can mix both with markdown. If all you want is highlighting some rows/columns/cells, check [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#highlighting-cells). For mixing HTML and markdown, I suggest [formattable](http://renkun.me/formattable/).